# Inserção de imagem background responsivo em html.twig para o Drupal 8

Tags: twig, layout-responsivo, drupal, background-image

Estou tentando inserir uma **imagem como background responsivo** em um **html.twig** para o **Drupal 8**, porém sem sucesso. Não estou encontrando uma solução para isto. Melhor ainda se fosse algo prático como um "*coloque essa linha exatamente neste local*". A imagem simplesmente não aparece e ainda, em algumas soluções que encontrei, acabam anulando o restante do conteúdo textual.

Segue como está o arquivo:

```html
<div class="layout-container">

  <header role="banner">
    {% if logo %}
      <a href="{{ front_page }}" title="{{ 'Home'|t }}" rel="home">
        <img src="{{link.object.handle:'_images/arquivo.jpg'}}" width="100%" alt="{{link.title | mic_01}}" />
      </a>
    {% endif %}
  </header>

  <main role="main">
    {% if title %}
      <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    {% endif %}

    {{ page.highlighted }}

    {{ page.content }}
  </main>

  {% if page.footer %}
    <footer role="contentinfo">
      {{ page.footer }}
    </footer>
  {% endif %}

</div>{# /.layout-container #}
```

Comment: Qual erro aparece? Poderia detalhar melhor sua dificuldade?

Comment: A imagem simplesmente não aparece e ainda, em algumas soluções que encontrei, acabam anulando o restante do conteúdo em texto.

Comment: Mas não esta faltando apontar a fonte da imagem com o atributo `src`?

Comment: @gato Pois então, tentei as soluções comuns para HTML e CSS, porém parece que a linha "<img alt="{{ 'Home'|t }}"/>" não tem aceitado as mesmas. Já tentei no HTML: <img src="../images/arquivo.jpg">; e no CSS: background-image: url("images/arquivo.jpg"). O Twig se mostrou um tanto confuso até agora para mim. Parece-me que o problema está mais no "aonde colocar" do que "o que colocar". Editei a pergunta e inseri a última linha que testei referente à imagem "<img src(...)".

Comment: Mas aonde você está armazenando a sua imagem? O que tem antes do caminho `images/arquivo.jpg`?

Comment: @gato é localhost, no diretório do tema como segue: tema/images/arquivo.jpg. Já o html.twig como segue: tema/templates/layout/tema.html.twig.

Comment: Tente assim: `<img src="{{ base_path ~ directory }}/images/mic_01.jpg" alt="Meu logo" />`

Comment: @gato ótimo! Maravilha! Bom, o 1º e principal problema resolvido: a imagem está visível, apenas sem a necessidade do alt="Meu logo", já que está integrado no title="{{ 'Home'|t }}" uma linha acima. Entretanto ainda há o 2º problema da questão que é a responsividade. Tentei agora width="100%" dentro da tag, porém o mesmo cobre apenas o "padding" e não a "margin" completa, tampouco style="margin:100%" solucionou. Como proceder diante disto?

Comment: Ainda sem solução completa, pois, apesar da imagem aparecer, várias tentativas minhas simplesmente não mostram solução para um background-image responsivo. Seja em linha ou em link externo com um style em .css. Uma outra alternativa foi inserir no arquivo a linha: background-image: url("../images/mic_01.jpg"); porém sem sucesso também.

Answer (score 0):

Se a sua imagem for um arquivo estático tente trocar o caminho:

```
<img src="<CAMINHO DIRETO PARA A IMAGEM>" width="100%" alt="{{link.title | mic_01}}" />
```

Caso ela seja dinâmica você pode tentar processar a URL da imagem dentro de um [hook preprocess](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/9.1.x) dentro do seu tema (arquivo **.theme**), por exemplo:

```
function [ID_DO SEU_TEMA]_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $variables['imagem'] = $url_to_image;
}
```